# Surjective morphism of varieties with finite fibers but not "finite"

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ and $Y$ be affine varieties, and $f : X \to Y$ a dominant regular map. Following Shafarevich, I will call $f$ finite if the induced map on coordinate rings is integral.

One consequence of finiteness is that the fibers are finite, and that $f$ is surjective. Can someone provide an example of a regular $f$ that satisfies these set theoretic properties but fails to be finite?

Are there conditions under which these necessary conditions become sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) The surjective  regular map  $\mathbb A^1_k\setminus \{1\}\hookrightarrow \mathbb A^1_k:z\mapsto z^2$ has fibers of cardinality one over $1\in \mathbb A^1_k$ and $0\in \mathbb A^1_k$ and all the other fibers have cardinality two.
Nevertheless that map is not finite because the morphism on coordinate rings is  $k[T]\hookrightarrow k[T,\frac {1}{T-1}]:T\mapsto T^2$, which is not an integral ring morphism.

2) Add properness to guarantee finiteness:

> A morphism between algebraic varieties (affine or not) is finite if and only if   it is proper and has finite fibers.

Comment: This last fact that Georges has quoted is highly non-trivial. It is one version of Zariski's Main Theorem!